# What is omitted in the idiom "do somebody good"?

Tags: grammar, idioms

An example sentence: "Exercising regularly would do you good."

Is a word such as **"things"**, is omitted in this idiom?
("**Exercising regularly would do you good (things).**")

I don't get why an *adjective*(=**good**), but not a *noun* comes after '**you**'.
This doesn't sound grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is omitted. "Good" is used here as a noun.

Dictionary.com provides the [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/good?s=t)

> *Noun:* profit or advantage; worth; benefit:

Answer (score 1):

Here good is not an adjective but it is a noun. here good  means benefit

You are good. Here  good is an adjective.

**If you do good to others , they will do good to you**

Answer (score 1):

The sentence and usage are correct. Here **good** is used as a noun. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/good) has

> **good**
>   NOUN
>
> **2** *[mass noun]* Benefit or advantage to someone or something.
>   *he is too clever for his own good*